# 3d model camera position and look direction

Tags: c#, helix-3d-toolkit

I use helixtoolkit for my dynamic obj loader.I have an combobox with up view and front view.

I know I have to write something to change the camera position and look direction.

This code I have used with a button click to move the obj a little bit.

```
            var axis = new Vector3D(0, 0, 1);
            var angle = 10;

            var matrix = objmodel.Transform.Value;
            matrix.Rotate(new Quaternion(axis, angle));

            objmodel.Transform = new MatrixTransform3D(matrix);
```

Anyone can provide help , I am not very good at coding...

Comment: I would suggest starting on something a bit more basic if you're learning how to code...

Comment: Even the best coders sometimes need help...

Comment: Oh, I'm not saying you shouldn't be asking for help, just saying that learning to code using 3d transformations and stuff is... ambitious. I would have started with, say, tic-tac-toe, but that's me :).

Comment: No problem... but there is no turn back for me anymore , I have to solve this asap..

Comment: What version of helixtoolkit are you using? Do you use the ViewportClass and if yes the WPF or WPFSharpDX one?

Comment: Helixtoolkit 2.1.0 and I use wpf , viewport             `<h:HelixViewport3D x:Name="myView" ZoomExtentsWhenLoaded="True" Margin="-228,-38,-128,10">`